# Optimisation on postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for optimization suggestions for the below query on postgres. Not a DBA so looking for some expert advice in here.

Devices table holds device_id which are hexadecimal.
To achieve high throughput we run 6 instances of this query in parallel with pattern matching for device_id 
beginning with [0-2], [3-5], [6-9], [a-c], [d-f]

When we run just one instance of the query it works fine, but with 6 instances we get error - 
[6669]:FATAL: connection to client lost

```
explain analyze select notifications.id, notifications.status, events.alert_type,
  events.id as event_id, events.payload, notifications.device_id as device_id,
  device_endpoints.region, device_endpoints.device_endpoint as endpoint
  from notifications
  inner join events
  on notifications.event_id = events.id
  inner join devices
  on notifications.device_id = devices.id
  inner join device_endpoints   
  on devices.id = device_endpoints.device_id
  where notifications.status = 'pending' AND notifications.region = 'ap-southeast-2' 
  AND devices.device_id ~ '[0-9a-f].*'
  limit 10000;
```

Output of explain analyse

```
"Limit  (cost=25.62..1349.23 rows=206 width=202) (actual time=0.359..0.359 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=25.62..1349.23 rows=206 width=202) (actual time=0.357..0.357 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (notifications.device_id = devices.id)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=25.33..1258.73 rows=206 width=206) (actual time=0.357..0.357 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=25.04..61.32 rows=206 width=52) (actual time=0.043..0.172 rows=193 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (notifications.event_id = events.id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using idx_notifications_status on notifications  (cost=0.42..33.87 rows=206 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.100 rows=193 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (status = 'pending'::notification_status)"
"                          Filter: (region = 'ap-southeast-2'::text)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=16.50..16.50 rows=650 width=40) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..16.50 rows=650 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.014 rows=34 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using idx_device_endpoints_device_id on device_endpoints  (cost=0.29..5.80 rows=1 width=154) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=193)"
"                    Index Cond: (device_id = notifications.device_id)"
"        ->  Index Scan using devices_pkey on devices  (cost=0.29..0.43 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)"
"              Index Cond: (id = device_endpoints.device_id)"
"              Filter: (device_id ~ '[0-9a-f].*'::text)"
"Planning time: 0.693 ms"
"Execution time: 0.404 ms"
```

Comment: The error `FATAL: connection to client lost` sounds like you have a problem with how you connect to the DB. Solve this problem before you try to optimize the query, which, BTW, looks fine alreay.

Comment: Your query is very fast; I don't see the problem. If this is just a small sample, the `EXPLAIN` is worthless; we need the real thing (with `BUFFERS` enabled, if possible). The error probably means that PostgreSQL has crashed; please share the relevant lines from the log file. Are you using an old version of PostgreSQL so that you cannot use parallel query?

Comment: This really looks like a connection handling/management issue and not an "optimization" issue. Which language/framework do you use to handle the connections, execute the queries and how does the code looks like for coordinating them? Also, is there any kind of proxy in between? pgbouncer? pgpool? ...?

Comment: We are using pg-promise module of nodejs to interface with postgresql. Postgresql(9.6.8) is hosted on Aurora Postgres. We increased the poolSize from 2 to 10 and also increased the instance size from  db.r4.xlarge to db.r4.2xlarge, since the CPU usage was going to 100%. The logs are clean now. I am not sure what changes made it work but everything seems good for now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: From optimisation point of view, will creating an index on notification.status column add some value? It is an enum type and can have any of the 4 values.

Comment: OK, glad you made it work. You need to watch pool-size and ensure you always have a few connections free for out-of-line and/or parallel work. Hopefully you have made sure that with 10 available connections, you are never ever executing that query twice in parallel. For the optimization: my personal experience is that for very large tables, the upgrade to PostgreSQL 11 (but at least 10) brings in huge performance improvements due to parallel scans which may obsolete the separate connections approach.

Comment: Thanks @Ancoron. Upgrading to 10.6, as that is the highest we can go with AWS Aurora. Can you please elaborate on ur comment - "Hopefully you have made sure that with 10 available connections, you are never ever executing that query twice in parallel" as I have not taken care of any such thing. Thanks

Comment: Nice to hear about the upgrade. I assumed with "poolSize" you were referring to the number of connections created for pg-promise and that were executing the 6 different queries in parallel, each having their own connection. If that's the case, you'd just have 4 connections left, not another 6 for a second set of 6 parallel queries. Apart from that, running an intensive query (btw. you still didn't publish any `explain (analyze, buffers)` from a real query on the full data set) multiple times concurrently will make the response times slow down much more mainly because of even more random I/O.

Comment: Speaking of I/O: if you would provide a real `explain (analyze, buffers)` after you have enabled `track_io_timing`, we would likely see the impact of I/O operations on your query, which might be the actual bottleneck. Therefore, you should also check how many IOPS you have bought. It might make sense to spend a bit more money on IOPS than on RAM or CPU.